# Command not working in .profile

Tags: command-line

In my .profile I have the following command,

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Right now, to get my desired behavior I have to type `source ~/.profile` in the terminal. I would like this to be automatic (since it's in .profile), but it's not. Any ideas?

My .profile is being executed when I login (tested it with `export foo=bar`).

Comment: What's in `rvm`? That looks like the weak link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.profile` is not only used by bash, it's also used by other posix shells. When you log in graphically in Ubuntu, `~/.profile` gets sourced by `sh`, which does not have `[[` or `source`.

*EDIT*

After a bit of googling about this rvm stuff, it appears it's a bash script, so switching to posix sh syntax won't work; the script simply does not belong in `~/.profile`.

One way to get around it could be to source it from `~/.bashrc` instead. The drawback of that is that whatever environment variables it sets, will only be available to bash shells. e.g. commands that rely on these enviornment variables can't be run directly from a launcher.

Comment: This worked. But, side-effect is that I can no longer login through graphical login manager. When I login, the login screen just closes and then shows again. Do you know why?

Comment: @Stuart Sounds like this rvm script is doing something it shouldn't, then.

Comment: When I put `export foo=$SHELL` into my ~/.profile, I get bash as the response. Shouldn't it give sh by what you said?

Comment: Edit: Or does Lightdm invoke bash as sh? That would explain why my .bash_profile isn't getting run.

Comment: @Stuart The `SHELL` environment variable reflects the login shell set in the passwd database (`/etc/passwd`). It does not reflect what shell you're currently in. To see what shell you're currently in, `ps -p $$` will tell you with most shells. With the `ps` command available in Ubuntu, you can narrow the output with `ps -ocmd= -p $$`. So: `export "foo=$(ps -ocmd= -p $$)"`.

Comment: @Stuart At any rate, as far as I know, there's no login shell involved. With gdm, which was used in earlier Ubuntu releases, an sh script was run when you logged in, that specifically sourced `~/.profile` before doing an `exec gnome-session`. Not sure how it's done with lightdm exactly, but it appears to be done similarly.

Comment: @Stuart edit: err, I meant `-ocomm=`, not `-ocmd=`.

Comment: Interesting, the output of the `ps` command is `lightdm-session`. Thank you for all your help!