# .profile not beeing sourced

Tags: kubuntu, environment-variables, .profile

some time ago I installed byobu and ran `byobu-enable` and it still didn't started automatically, I just ignored it since I could just press super and open up byobu terminal directly. But now I tried to set some variables and found this line on `~/.profile` :

```
byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch 2>/dev/null || true
```

and even when I set anything there the `~/.profile` file is never sourced. I know it is never sourced because my `$HOME/bin` is being set there and `echo $PATH` outputs:

```
/usr/local/clang_9.0.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

when I run `source ~/.profile` everything there works exactly as I expected, but that's not .profile behavior.

I've looked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/251933/profile-is-not-sourced-on-startup) [here](https://superuser.com/questions/176404/bash-not-loading-profile-in-new-session-on-linux) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307023/command-not-working-in-profile) and other posts and still nothing.

my ~/.profile :

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

_byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch 2>/dev/null || true
```

any ideas?

*edit*: I do have the `$HOME/bin` directory

Comment: I'm on kubuntu 20.04

Comment: sorry I didn't mentioned. Yes it exists

Comment: It may be something with [KDE/SDDM](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9pt1sl/any_idea_why_profile_is_not_loaded_on_restart/). If what you want to achieve is that the thing is launched at log in, using [autostart](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-apps-auto-start.html) is an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I switched distros (for others reasons) and I found the problem, in case some one needs it.

I use zsh as my main shell and it uses `.zprofile` instead of `.profile`, witch is used by bash. So the solution is either use the `.zprofile` file or use bash just to use `.profile` and then, after it gets sourced, you can change the shell to zsh (or ksh, dash, fish, etc), you just need to add `export SHELL=/bin/zsh` on your `.profile`

you can easily change shell with `chsh -s $(which bash)`, considering you have `which` command installed.